# subscribe getting called after below codes execution?

Tags: angular

I have a code that looks like this -

```
ngOnInit(){
          console.log("ngOnInit before service call");
          this._blockCreditCardService.getAccountList().
              subscribe(
                (data)=> {
                          this.accountList=data;
                          console.log("account-list-"+this.accountList[0])
                          console.log(this.accountList.length);
                          if(this.accountList.length>0){
                            this.nonEmptyAccountList=true;
                          }
                          this.options=[];
                          for (let i = 0; i < this.accountList.length; i++) {
                            this.options.push({ value: this.accountList[i], label:this.accountList[i].accountNumber});
                          }
                },
                error=> console.log("Error"),
                ()=> console.info("Completed")
               );
          this.selectedCardFromVerify=[];
          console.log("ngOnInit this.cardDetails-"+this.cardDetails);
          (this.cardDetails) ? this.reSelected(this.cardDetails) : this.isAccountSelected=false;

        }
```

and the result is

```
ngOnInit before service call
capture.component.ts?dfa9:125 ngOnInit this.cardDetails-undefined
core.es5.js?0445:3231 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
capture.component.ts?dfa9:111 account-list-[object Object]
```

on browser's console. What am i missing here. Why this is happening. i am new to angular 2 and would like someone to shed some light over here. Thanks.

Comment: do you understand the concept of asynchronous function?

Comment: Your service makes an AJAX request. The A in AJAX means **Asynchronous**. The whole point of subscribing and passing a callback is to be... called back later, when the response is available. Just like, when you eat your breakfast, you grill a toast, then read your newspaper, then only start eating your toast when the toaster dings to tell you "your toast is ready". If the service call was synchronous, it wouldn't return an observable. It would directly return the result.

Answer (score 2):

The subscribe is asynchronous, so that service call starts and the rest of the function continues while the subscribe is waiting for data, and then that thread continues when the data comes back, so your ngOnInit console log runs first because the service hasn't finished returning data yet.

If you want the remaining instructions to happen after the data comes back, you need to move them into the subscription block after you've assigned the data to this.accountList=data.

```
ngOnInit(){
          console.log("ngOnInit before service call");
          this._blockCreditCardService.getAccountList().
              subscribe(
                (data)=> {
                          this.accountList=data;
                          console.log("account-list-"+this.accountList[0])
                          console.log(this.accountList.length);
                          if(this.accountList.length>0){
                            this.nonEmptyAccountList=true;
                          }
                          this.options=[];
                          for (let i = 0; i < this.accountList.length; i++) {
                            this.options.push({ value: this.accountList[i], label:this.accountList[i].accountNumber});
                          }
                          this.selectedCardFromVerify=[];
                          console.log("ngOnInit this.cardDetails-"+this.cardDetails);
                          (this.cardDetails) ? this.reSelected(this.cardDetails) : this.isAccountSelected=false;

                },
                error=> console.log("Error"),
                ()=> console.info("Completed")
               );

        }
```

Comment: Though i got a lot of downvotes for my question but atleast i got the answer. Thanks. I am not only new to angular but also new to UI.

Comment: It can be frustrating to ask for help and get negative responses instead. Don't let it get you down, just try and ask clear and concise questions and provide as much evidence that you tried working out the problem yourself first before you turned to StackOverflow, and you should be fine. I'm glad I could help. If my answer was the best, if you could mark it as such that would be appreciated. Cheers!